# Get rid of [endless]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

The [endless](/questions/tagged/endless) tag lacks a tag wiki and should be cleaned up. Possible replacements are things like:

- [endless-scroll](/questions/tagged/endless-scroll) (which in turn should be a synonym of [infinite-scroll](/questions/tagged/infinite-scroll))
- [endless-loop](/questions/tagged/endless-loop) (which in turn should be a synonym of [infinite-loop](/questions/tagged/infinite-loop))

Comment: And questions about endless loops should get the [tag:infinite-loop] tag.

Comment: I've done a couple were it was obvious what to do...

Comment: There's also the [endlessadapter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/endlessadapter) tag that's appropriate for some of the Android questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [endless](/questions/tagged/endless) tag is no more.

Also, [endless-scroll](/questions/tagged/endless-scroll) is now a synonym of [infinite-scroll](/questions/tagged/infinite-scroll), and [endless-loop](/questions/tagged/endless-loop) is a synonym of [infinite-loop](/questions/tagged/infinite-loop).  Both synonyms are merged with their master tag.